# How to call .toggleClass "selected" on all rows in jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, datatables

I wish to add a "Select All" button to my datatable that would allow all rows that are not-filtered to call `.toggleClass "selected"` so as to then perform other function calls on.

However, after creating the action below it does not allow for the select all:

```
 $("#selectAllLocations").click ->
    allRows = $("#restaurantLocations").dataTable().fnGetNodes()
    for aRow in allRows
      aRow.toggleClass "selected"
```

But leads to the error:

[image]

on the line `aRow.toggleClass "selected"`

How can this 'Select All' button be implemented?

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo but shouldn't it be aRow.toggleClass('selected') and not aRow.toggleClass "selected"???

Comment: I got this to work by simply calling: `table.$("tr").addClass "Selected"`, I was over thinking it

Comment: What is the output (on console) of `console.log(allRows)`?